# Problem Xvfb using python 2.7 and selenium

Tags: python, linux, selenium, xvfb

I have a problem using "Xvfb" with Selenium. In my requirement i have to open python with a bash script. if i execute it normally python like

```
python file.py
```

it doesn't have any problem, but if i execute it directly from bash the following error happens

```
start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-help'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
```

I don't know what happends, my code in python (where the error appears)

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
```

and bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
MODULE="/home/user/file.py"
$PYTHON $MODULE
```

I will be grateful for any response

Edit:
Full message in Except

```
Problem to open browser: start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-help'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
EXCEPTION IN (main.py, LINE 2148 "display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))"): start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-help'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first check if `python -V` and `/usr/bin/python -V` shows the same version  of Python.

Comment: do you run it as the same user ? Directly in terminal/console and not in `cron` or other manager? With the same privilages? In the same virtualenv - or without virtualenv?

Comment: @furas i run it in terminal, without virtualenv and the same user and privilages. 
Python version 2.7.13 in python -v and /usr/bin/python -V